# Google Drive and PostScript; How to restore .ps features?

Tags: postscript

Very few fancier PostScript programs will Artifex display on Google Drive.

I've slowly been adding and repairing what I can via entries at 
https://www.tinaja.com/whtnu19.shtml So far, I've only been able
to get a modified 20 of my 2000+ programs to run properly.

I've managed to at least get workarounds for the lack of error
reporting or log files. Some links are now working as well.

It turns out there are no full or partial pathnames in Google Drive, which
uses cloud-wide id's instead.

How can I define a PS read file?

How can I run a PS file as a subroutine as, say, (gonzo.ps) run. Distiller
allows this via its secret /F incantation.

How can I write a modified bitmap as PostScript output. This is super
important for eBay photography.

I'd like to see Google Drive doing the exact same thing that Distiller does.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like its a PostScript question. Do these files run in Ghostscript ? If so then the problems are in Google's implementation. I'm assuming you mean Ghostscript when you say Artifex here.

A lot (all ?) of your questions seem particular to Google's implementation. Ghostscript writes error and back channel information to stdout and stderr, normally you can redirect these to files. Not being familiar with Google Drive I can't really say how (or indeed if) you could do that in that environment.

I've no idea what you mean by 'run a PS file as a subroutine', nor am I familiar with the /F switch to Distiller. Perhaps if you explained what you mean here it might be possible to make suggestions.

If Google is using some kind of file system of its own, I don't see any realistic way that you can use the `run` operator. I'd also be fairly surprised if Google is not using `-dSAFER` which would probably prevent you doing that anyway.

This would also, presumably, prevent you 'writing a modified bitmap', because I would guess you can't open a file for writing (even if you can, how would you know its ID).

But really, these are not PostScript questions.